# Migration to postgres doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, asp.net-core

So I've built a very Asp.Net Core 3.0 MVC app, with some models and when I run the `add-migration initial`, it runs with no errors and it shows up in the solution explorer, but no changes occur in the actual PostgreSQL database.

I've noticed when I mess with the connection string, and put wrong stuff there, it only matters when I want to remove the migration, it gives no error when I want to add the migration.

I'm using .net core 3.0 , PostgreSQL 12.1.

`ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(opt => opt.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection")));
```

Connection string in `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DbConnection" :  "User ID =postgres;Password=pass;Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=MyDb;Integrated Security = True; Pooling=true"
  },
```

DbContext:

```
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<PirkVald> PirkValds { get; set; }
    }
```

Console output when running `add-migration initial`

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 3.1.0 initialized 'MyDbContext' using provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL' with options: None
To undo this action, use Remove-Migration.
```

Comment: see this documents http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/

Comment: I followed it, but it comes up with errors anyway. This simplest thing seems so god-damn impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Update-database` to apply your migration and refresh your PostgreSQL database